# Where does params[:id] come from in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am a beginner of Rails. I am learning rails with the book 'Beginning Rails 4' now. I want to ask you about 'parameter' passed to params method. The following is one of typical rails controllers.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_article
  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: 'Thanks for your comment'
    else
      redirect_to @article, alert: 'Unable to add comment'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @article, notice: 'Comment Deleted'
  end

  private
    def load_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body)
    end
  end
```

Yes, this is just a typical comment controller used to create a comment attached to an article. The Comment model 'belongs to' the Article model, and the Article model 'has many' comments.

Take look at the destroy method.

```
def destroy
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  -- snip --
end
```

It finds the comment associated with the article by find(params[:id]). My question is, where on earth does params[:id] come from?

Does it come from URL? Or does rails save params hash automatically whenever any comment record is created? So we can find any comment by find(params[:id])?

The load_article method is similar.

```
def load_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
end
```

It finds an article by params[:article_id]. Where does this params[:article_id] come from? How does rails find an article by this?

Comment: It comes from the URL, maybe reading the routing section of the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) will help you understand it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`params[:id]` is meant to be the string that uniquely identifies a (RESTful) resource within your Rails application. It is found in the URL after the resource's name.

For example, for a resource called `my_model`, a `GET` request should correspond to a URL like `myserver.com/my_model/12345`, where `12345` is the `params[:id]` that identifies that specific instance of `my_model`. Analogies follow for the other HTTP requests (PUT, DELETE etc) and their RESTful counterparts.

You should read about [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and its interpretation of RESTful architecture if you're still confused about these concepts and terminologies.

Answer (score 4):

`params[:id]` does come from the URL. When you use `resources` in your routes file, Rails will automatically generate the standard REST routes for you. In your `destroy` example, that would usually be a be a request to `/comments/:id` using the `DELETE` HTTP method, in which that `:id` is added to the `params` hash, i.e. `params[:id]`.